# Insert con DO WHILE (fechas)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla temporal llamada `#Columnas` con `INSERTS` (son 31 registros fechas) pero necesito ayuda:

1. Necesito usar un bucle `DO WHILE` para agregar los 31 registros porque escribir `insert` para cada fecha es molesto.
2. Con respecto a las fechas, comienza desde las `'2019-06-24 08:00:00'` pero necesito que avance cada 20 minutos, por ejemplo:

   ```
   '2019-06-24 08:00:00',
   '2019-06-24 08:20:00', 
   '2019-06-24 08:40:00' 
   sucesivamente hasta las 
   '2019-06-24 18:00:00'.
   ```

Este es la creación de la tabla `#Columnas`:

```
CREATE TABLE #Columnas(
Columna Int Identity(1, 1), 
Rango DateTime, 
Cantidad int)
```

Estos son los 31 registros:

```
INSERT INTO #Columnas (Rango)  SELECT '2019-06-24 08:00:00' 
INSERT INTO #Columnas (Rango)  SELECT '2019-06-24 08:20:00' 
INSERT INTO #Columnas (Rango)  SELECT '2019-06-24 08:40:00' 
INSERT INTO #Columnas (Rango)  SELECT '2019-06-24 09:00:00' 
.
.
.
INSERT INTO #Columnas (Rango)  SELECT '2019-06-24 18:00:00'
```

Esto es lo que he avanzado (no se si es necesario hacerlo con un `procedure` pero es lo que encontré):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_ColumnasRango
AS
DECLARE @hid INT;
SET @hid = 1;
WHILE @hid < 32
BEGIN
    INSERT #Columnas(Rango,Cantidad)
    VALUES ('2019-06-24 14:20:00', NULL)
    SET @hid = @hid + 1;
END
```

Y esto es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sucesivamente hasta: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me podría ayudar que hacer con respecto a la fecha para que avance cada 20 minutos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola amigo prueba con esto declare una tabla Tipo variable solo para efectos de prueba.
Tu la puedes remplazar con la tuya y llevar la logica a tu sp

```
DECLARE @Columnas TABLE(
Columna Int Identity(1, 1), 
Rango DateTime, 
Cantidad int) 

--DECLARAMOS LA FECHA DE INICIO QUE SE DESEE
DECLARE @FechaDemo DATETIME='2019-06-24 08:00:00' 
DECLARE @Inicio INT=1;
DECLARE @Total INT=31

WHILE @Inicio<=@Total
BEGIN
--DATEADD AL PASARLE EL PARAMETRO MINUTE se le dice que ira aumentando de 20 minutos en 20 Minutos de acuerdo a la fecha que se recibe en este caso la variable @FechaDemo
INSERT INTO @Columnas (Rango)  SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,20,@FechaDemo)
--A nuestra fecha inicial (@FechaDemo) le agregamos los otros 20 minutos anteriores para que cuando regrese tenga esta fecha mas los nuevos 20 minutos.
SET @FechaDemo=DATEADD(MINUTE,20,@FechaDemo)
SET @Inicio=@Inicio+1
END


SELECT * FROM @Columnas
```

Saludos

Comment: Por qué este código resuelve el problema del OP? Procura siempre añadir una breve explicación de lo que hace el código que sugieres usar.

Comment: Claro muchas gracias lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas declarar un cursor o hacer un procedimiento para esto, puedes derivar la información directamente en una *tabla* e insertar los datos a tu tabla temporal, si fuese necesario.

Primero, para obtener estas 31 filas, puedes valerte de una tabla del diccionario de datos que usualmente tenga muchas filas, por ejemplo `sys.all_columns`, que generalmente va a tener varios miles de filas.

Para obtener intervalos de 20 minutos, sugiero obtener el número de fila, multiplicarlo por 20 y aplicarlo directamente a la hora inicial usando `dateadd()`, en código luciría como lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @FechaIni DateTime = '20190715 08:00:00' ;

select top 31 
       dateadd(minute, (row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1) * 20, @FechaIni) Fecha
  from sys.all_columns
```

Que nos devuelve:

```
Fecha
-----------------------
2019-07-15 08:00:00.000
2019-07-15 08:20:00.000
2019-07-15 08:40:00.000
2019-07-15 09:00:00.000
2019-07-15 09:20:00.000
2019-07-15 09:40:00.000
2019-07-15 10:00:00.000
2019-07-15 10:20:00.000
2019-07-15 10:40:00.000
2019-07-15 11:00:00.000
2019-07-15 11:20:00.000
2019-07-15 11:40:00.000
2019-07-15 12:00:00.000
2019-07-15 12:20:00.000
2019-07-15 12:40:00.000
2019-07-15 13:00:00.000
2019-07-15 13:20:00.000
2019-07-15 13:40:00.000
2019-07-15 14:00:00.000
2019-07-15 14:20:00.000
2019-07-15 14:40:00.000
2019-07-15 15:00:00.000
2019-07-15 15:20:00.000
2019-07-15 15:40:00.000
2019-07-15 16:00:00.000
2019-07-15 16:20:00.000
2019-07-15 16:40:00.000
2019-07-15 17:00:00.000
2019-07-15 17:20:00.000
2019-07-15 17:40:00.000
2019-07-15 18:00:00.000

(31 rows affected)
```

Finalmente, si consideras que aún necesitas la tabla temporal, puedes insertar los valores de esta consulta con un `insert/select`, así:

```
CREATE TABLE #Columnas(
Columna Int Identity(1, 1), 
Rango DateTime, 
Cantidad int) 

insert into #Columnas (rango) 
select top 31 
       dateadd(minute, (row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1) * 20, @FechaIni) Fecha
  from sys.all_columns
```

El código es más corto, en mi opinión más fácil de leer y mantener y probablemente más eficiente que un cursor.